# React native Twitter Auth via Firebase Auth

Tags: twitter, oauth, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing Twitter auth into a React Native app, which uses bunch of Firebase features, including Firebase Auth.

As far as I'm concerned, neither Firebase Auth SDK nor FirebaseUI, which manages to carry whole authentication flow on web, hasn't been bridged to React Native yet(?). So I have to carry the first part of auth flow on my own. By the first part I mean get provider Access Token and turn it into credentials, which can then be passed to Firebase Auth *signInWithCredential*.

This is what I've done for Facebook using Facebook SDK.

```
const fbAuth = async () => {
    const result = await LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(facebookPermissions);

    if (result.isCancelled)
        throw error;

    const { accessToken } = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    const facebookCredential = firebaseAuth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken.toString());

    await firebaseAuth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential);
}
```

Firebase Auth than carries the rest for me and I'm successfully done.

I would like to do the same thing for Twitter. Unfortunately there is no Twitter SDK, that would allow me to achieve this in couple of steps like Facebook SDK.

It seems I will have to do the whole OAuth dance for Access Token on my own.

I would like get some opinions what are the best practices to approach this situation.

**Twitter Use-case**
According to Twitter [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing) I have to perform direct calls to the API. The calls obviously contain secrets, which cannot be stored in a client app and I don't really fancy creating an Auth server (as I'm not sure about how would the flow work). I would like to keep this as much client-level as possible.

Would love to hear opinions on how to achieve this and what would the flow look like.

Comment: any luck in finding a simple solution like for facebook?

Comment: Haven't investigated this further, nope.